# Force download image from different server html

Tags: php, html

I have a link, that after click the link, user can download image. Right now, after click the link, user only can viewed the image.

How can I make browser to make after user click link, it will force to download the image

Here's the code

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title> Download-Images</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> Click the link ! You can download Image </p>
    <a download="logo.png" href="https://w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" title="Logo title" target="_blank">
    link
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried added php code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401254/php-force-download-from-different-domains) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214778/force-to-download-image-from-external-server) in below my html code, but it's not working.

Comment: Please do not just refer us to other questions, saying “it’s not working”, that is not helpful at all. Show us what exactly you tried, inside your own question, and give a proper problem description along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I have tested on my localhost and it worked.

html:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title> Download-Images</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> Click the link ! You can download Image </p>
    <a href="download.php?url=https://w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" title="Logo title">
    link
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

download.php

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
if ($url != '')
{
    $filename = end(explode('/', $url));
    $fileext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename)));
    
    if ($fileext == 'jpg' || $fileext == 'jpeg') { $type = 'image/jpeg'; }
    if ($fileext == 'png') { $type = 'image/png'; }
    if ($fileext == 'gif') { $type = 'image/gif'; }
    
    //$size = filesize($url);
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    //header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    readfile($url);
}else{
    echo 'url is blank';
}
?>
```